# how to locate resources in Symfony2 outside controllers?

Tags: symfony

I know that in Symfony 2 we can use from a controller the service kernel to locate resources,  like this:

```
$yamlFileKeys   = $this->get('kernel')->locateResource('@CgboardAppBundle/Resources/config/myfile.yml');
```

My question is more about how can we locate resources when we are not in a controller?, I tried the same before like:

```
file_get_contents('@CgboardAppBundle/Resources/config/myfile.yml')
```

And the resource was never found. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the file you want to load.
If you want to load, process and validate config files, there is a really powerful component to do this:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/introduction.html

If you want to load other Filetypes there is another Component, the Finder component
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html

So if you just want to process a .yml file you can use the YAML component and the Finder component
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$yaml = new Parser();

$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()->in(__DIR__);

foreach ($finder as $file) {
    $values = $yaml->parse($file->getContents());
    ...
}
```